# What is actually a simple sentence?

Tags: dependent-clause

From "**[Literary Devices](https://literarydevices.net/simple-sentence/)**" (literarydevices.net)

> A simple sentence in grammar has only one main or
>   independent clause and no dependent or subordinate clauses. Comprising
>   a subject and a predicate, this short and independent syntactic entity
>   intends to convey a complete idea or meanings of an idea.
>
> Example #2: The Awakening (by Kate Chopin)
>
> “She was becoming herself and daily casting aside that fictitious self
>   which we assume like a garment with which to appear before the world.”
>
> This is another excellent example of a simple sentence without the use
>   of commas. It is just a single sentence without dependent clauses.

The question: Does the above example sentence not include a dependent clause?

If no, what is "***which we assume like a garment with which to appear before the world***" in the sentence?

Comment: How do you define a dependent clause? Have you looked up "main clause" and "dependent clause" in a good grammar source?

Comment: @Kris. As far as my little knowledge is concerned, a main clause is independent with a complete thought (here, "She was becoming herself and daily casting aside that fictitious self".) A subordinate/dependent (when begun with a subordinate conjunction) or a relative clause (a sort of dependent clause, begun with a relative pronoun) is a clause - having its own subject and predicate - that lacks a complete thought, so that it cannot stand alone without the support of an independent clause. In the above example, I think, "which we assume like a garment with which to appear before the world".

Comment: If I'm wrong, please help me with a clarification.

Comment: It is two things.  First, if this is a sound example of a 'simple' sentence, then the word 'simple' is a poor one for the characteristic.  The German for "Give me a garment in which to appear" is "Gib ir ein Kleidungsstück, in dem sie erscheinen soll "; the Greek would similarly use a dependent clause.  It cannot be that the same statement in different languages, with the same number of dependent ideas be described as expressed in a 'simple sentence' in some but not simple in others.  If so, then maybe it is time to rethink the idea of syntactic simplicity.

Comment: It wasn't criticism. My point was that when posting a question, we are **required** to show background effort, which in this case would mean that the OP cite a reliable source that defines the terms and then show why it is considered that the subject text is not obeying the said definitions. Good Luck.

Comment: @Tuffy Try again.

Comment: If this post gets migrated to [ell.se] then a simple answer can easily come forth there.

Comment: @Tuffy Yes, that can actually be very well. The structure of a clause, whether dependent or independent, is entirely language-dependent. In Greenlandic, I dare say “give me a garment in which to appear” could be expressed in just two words. The German (incidentally, your translation means “Give me an item of clothing in which she shall appear”) requires a relative clause, which do not even exist in all languages (Chinese doesn’t have them, for instance). Modern Greek has dependent clauses everywhere; Ancient Greek had very few. So yes, different languages can absolutely express it differently.

Comment: @mahmudkoya You’re absolutely right: the sentence quoted in that excerpt is not a simple sentence. The writer of that page is completely clueless as to what constitutes a single sentence. Of their six examples of ‘simple sentences’, three (#2, #3 and #4) are actually complex sentences with dependent clauses in them. I would stay well away from that site if I were you.

Comment: Certainly, this sentence would be classified as _complex_ and not _simple_ in both ESL and native-English pedagogical materials. For example, Holts Middle School Handbook, used in English classes, states (p206): _A complex sentence has one independent and at least one subordinate clause_. E.g. _Some of the sailors who took part in the mutiny...settled Pitcairn Island in the South Pacific_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Thank you. I feel now like I'm not alone!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ancient Greek is hardly short of subordinate clauses.  It did have alternatives to them, it is true, but in addition to the subjunctive mood, it also had an optative.  Modern Greek, on the other hand, got itself into a bit of a mess (I would say) with its rather strange ‘imperfective’, as it is called.

Comment: @Tuffy I meant it had few compared to Modern Greek – where MG needs a subordinate clause for every infinitive and tends to prefer clauses over participials, AG was the opposite, preferring infinitives and participials over subordinate clauses. I don’t see how the subjunctive and optative really have anything to do with this, apart from being moods mainly used in subordinate clauses.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’m not sure this is strictly true, though it may be.  i suspect the relative proportions vary with the purpose of writing.  So for philosophy and rhetoric my sense is that clauses are preferred (to provide clear expression of premisses and conclusions.  For narrative the balance might move the other way.  Latin ha a great love of participle phrases and gerundives, and these (notably in the writings of Tacitus) provide that distinctive compression of expression.  But it is, for the reader, anything but simple!  But I am in danger of straying off topic!

Comment: This has been an interesting discussion in the comments - one of the highlights of recent EL&U browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I have already made a comment about the definition of “simple sentence in this context.

The Oxford Grammar uses “simple sentence” to contrast with “compound sentence”.  At 5.19 Greenbaum starts by distinguishing finite from non-finite verb phrases.

> A verb is finite, if it displays tense, that is, the distinction between present and past.

He goes on to explain

> A finite verb phrase can function as the verb phrase of a **simple sentence**, the verb of a main clause within a **compound sentence**, or the verb of a subordinate clause.

His example of a *simple sentence* makes it clear that he is using that terminology to indicate the absence of subordination.

> Tonight I’m *going* to my first cocktail party at the Commission, my dearest.

His examples of compound sentences all involve subordinate clauses.  But he goes on to say

> A non-finite verb phrase cannot function as the verb of a simple sentence or as the verb of a main clause within a compound sentence. It can, however, function as the verb of a non-finite subordinate clause.

“[19] I don’t recall *actually giving the name*.

He goes on to explain

> In [19] *giving* is the verb of an -ing participle **clause**.  It is a transitive verb, and its direct object is *the name*.

It is interesting that he calls a participle **clause**what I have always thought of as a participle **phrase**.  But I have argued in a comment that in OP’s question the participles are in effect functioning as verbs (which Greenbaum calls *non-finite*).

So I stick to my guns and say that the sentence quoted in the question is a compound sentence with subordinate clauses of which the verbs are non-finite.

Comment: A good answer, right up until the last sentence – the sentence quoted in the question is actually a compound sentence with two subordinate clauses: one non-finite (_with which to appear_) and one finite (_which we assume_). I’m not sure all grammars would call the infinitival one a subordinate clause, but there is definitely no grammar who would not consider the perfectly straightforward, finite relative clause _which we assume_ to be a subordinate clause.